# Regex not capturing number and string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

Hi all so I am trying to capture anything that begins with a number, but for some reason regex is not capturing the entries in my table:

```
df
   a
0 Shamrock1-A
1 Shamrock2-B
2
3 Q217
4 1YR
5 2YR
```

I am trying to capture Q217, 1YR and 2YR with the following regex:

```
(Q|^\d)
```

But my regex is only capturing Q217. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no Q417 in your example, and your regex cannot capture it anyway

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ my mistake, a typo

Comment: Your regex cannot capture Q217

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ I use str.contains to capture them, so by using (Q) it then captures Q217

Comment: Would this work?  `(^(Q|\d).*)`?  Or if you wanted to guaruntee that something came after the `Q` or `\d`, you could do `(^(Q|\d).+)`

Comment: Without more information about what to expect in the `a` column, it's hard to anticipate edge cases.

Comment: @codeninja is my answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As @Ghilas BELHADJ pointed out, you cannot regex capture "Q217". However, you can use regex to filter out the most obvious items and then filter:

```
import re

l = ["Shamrock1-A", "Shamrock2-B", "Q217", "1YR", "2YR"]

new_list = [re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+(?!-)|[0-9][a-zA-Z]+", i) for i in l]

final_list = [i[0] for i in new_list if i]
```

Output:

```
['Q217', '1YR', '2YR']
```

Comment: OP is working on a Pandas DataFrame, so, numbers from 0 to 5 are not part of the strings.

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ thank you for pointing that out. I have edited my response.

Comment: He's trying to capture "Q217" too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to capture any string that starts with a digit or starts with a Q, then you could do

```
(^(Q|\d).*)
```

If you wanted to make sure that the `'Q'` were followed by digits, you'd have

```
(^(Q\d+|\d.*))
```

If you wanted to guaruntee that something actually came after either the `'Q'` or the `\d`, you could do

```
(^(Q|\d).+)
```

And you could put a `$` after any of these pattern to ensure that nothing came after them (esp if the `'Q'` couldn't have alpha after the digits)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Shamrock1-A', 'Shamrock2-B', 'Q217', '1YR', '2YR']})
             a
0  Shamrock1-A
1  Shamrock2-B
2         Q217
3          1YR
4          2YR

df.a.str.extract('(^(Q|\d).*)')[0]

0     NaN
1     NaN
2    Q217
3     1YR
4     2YR
```

Comment: Why and how does this solve the problem? Those who can answer those questions for themselves don't need someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

This will catch all your examples and any more assuming capital letters. It is easy to add lower-case if that is required.

```
import re

text = '''
df
   a
0 Shamrock1-A
1 Shamrock2-B
2
3 Q217
4 1YR
5 2YR
'''

print( re.findall( '[A-Z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[A-Z]+', text ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works fine but you have to use `str.match` i.e

```
df[df['a'].str.match(r'Q|^\d')==True] # == True because of presence nan values
```

Output :

```
      a
3  Q217
4   1YR
5   2YR
```